# How do I enter special characters in text mode in dia?

Tags: special-characters, dia

How do I enter special characters in text mode in [dia](http://dia-installer.de/)? I am talking about the Greek characters like (alpha, beta, gamma or epsilon) or other mathematical symbols.

I am using dia in Ubuntu, if that is relevant in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any direct way. I write the symbol in Libreoffice (say psi, which comes as typing 3a8 and then pressing alt+X), and copy paste it to where I am writing in Dia, which works for me.